# Oracle Weblogic 10.3.6: missing SNI extension in SSL Handshake

Tags: java, tls1.2, weblogic11g, jsse, sni

I have an old Weblogic 11g where I'm trying to connect over a remote URL in HTTPS using TLSv1.2.

I have the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

What I have done:

- imported the certificates (server, intermediate and root) and key into the JKS keystore
- setting the keystore in weblogic
- activated JSSE SSL in weblogic
- enabled full SSL debug
- tried both with JDK7 and JDK8 (same behaviour)

The SSL debug reports this:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1525773762 bytes = { 197, 245, 78, 146, 106, 84, 201, 66, 238, 65, 60, 169, 137, 160, 237, 47, 29, 177, 82, 179, 112, 112, 86, 101, 253, 146, 29, 147 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 193
```

As you can see, **is missing the voice related to the server name extension**:

```
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: ... ]
```

I think that this is the cause of the handshake failure, because I obtain the same effect using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <%host.domain%>:443

CONNECTED(00000005)
4641384044:error:14004410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.200.4/libressl-2.6/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:1205:SSL alert number 40
4641384044:error:140040E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.200.4/libressl-2.6/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
```

while the following command (which specify the service name identifier) works perfectly:

```
openssl s_client -connect <%host.domain%>:443 -servername '<%host.domain%>'
```

I think that for some reason the JSSE or maybe the JDK is not setting the SNI parameter in the ClientHello step.

Any chance to configure it in order to force the usage of the SNI extension?